# Show that $F [\alpha,\beta]$ is a field if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $F$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

**My attempt** $:$

If $\alpha$ is algebraic over a field $F$ then by first isomorphism theorem it is clear that $$F [x] / (f (x)) \simeq F [\alpha]$$ where $f (x)$ is the irreducible polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F$.Now since $F [x]$ is a PID and $f (x)$ is irreducible over $F$ so $(f (x))$ is a maximal ideal and hence $F [x]/ (f (x))$ is a field and hence so is $F [\alpha]$.But then $F [\alpha] [y] = F [\alpha,y]$ is a PID. So again the application of first isomorphism theorem yields $$F [\alpha,y] / (g (y)) \simeq F [\alpha,\beta]$$ where $g (y)$ is the irreducible polynomial for $\beta$ over  $F [\alpha]$.But again by similar argunment mentioned above we have $F [\alpha,\beta]$ is a field.

Is my reasoning correct at all? Please check it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Completely correct. +1

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio for your verification.

Comment: But that conclusion will automatically lead us to the fact that $F [\alpha,\beta] = F (\alpha,\beta)$ if both of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic.Isn't it @DonAntonio?

Comment: @Ar Isn't that *exactly* what you just proved at the end of your post ? Perhaps though it'd be  better to write $$F(\alpha)[y]/(g(t))\cong F[\alpha,\beta]\;,\;\;g(t)\in F(\alpha)[t]\;\;\text{minimal for}\;\;\beta$$

Comment: Yeah if $F [\alpha]$ is a field then it is easy to see that $F [\alpha] = F (\alpha)$.

Comment: @DonAntonio  Why don't we need an additional hypothesis here that $F[\alpha, \beta]$ is contained in some field.  I thought $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$ and $\beta = \begin{pmatrix} c & -d \\ d & c-d \end{pmatrix}$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}$ would provide a counter-example.  $\alpha$ satisfies the equation $x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2$ and $\beta$ satisfies the equation $x^2-(2c-d)x+c^2-cd+d^2$, so $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $\Bbb{Q}[\beta]$ are both fields.  But $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha, \beta]$ is isomorphic to the ring of 2 x 2 matrices over $\Bbb{Q}$ and certainly not a field.

Comment: @sharding4 Who said we don't? Though it is trivially contained in the functions field $\;F(\alpha,\beta)\;$ ...Not to mention that your example uses polynomials valuated at matrices: that is messy, in general.

Comment: I found that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $F$ then $F [\alpha,\beta] = F [\alpha] [\beta] = F (\alpha) [\beta]$.Now since $\beta$ is algebraic over $F$ it is algebraic over $F (\alpha)$. So $F (\alpha) [\beta] = F (\alpha) (\beta)$.Now since $F(\alpha)$ and $\beta$ is contained in $F (\alpha,\beta)$ we find that $F (\alpha)(\beta) = F (\alpha,\beta)$.So we have $F [\alpha,\beta] = F (\alpha,\beta)$.